# Matlab cross validation and K-NN

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, knn

I am trying to build a knn clasiffier with cross validation in Matlab. Because of my MATLAB version I have used `knnclassify()` in order to build the classifier (`classKNN = knnclassify (sample_test, sample_training, training_label)`).

I am not capable to use `crossval()` with that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to perform the K-Nearest Neighbour in Matlab. The first one is by using `knnclassify()` as you did. However, this function will return the predicted labels and you cannot use `crossval()` with this. The cross-validation is performed on a model, not on its results. In Matlab, the model is described by an *object*.

`crossval()` only works with objects (classifier objects, be it K-NN, SVM and so on...). In order to create the so-called *nearest-neighbor classification object* you need to use the `fitcknn()` function. Given the Training Set and the Training Labels as input (in this order), such function will return your object, which you can give as input in `crossval()`.
There's only one thing left though: how do I predict the labels for my validation set? In order to do this, you need to use the `predict()` function. Given the model (kNN object) and the Validation Set as input (again, in this order), such function will return (as in `knnclassify()`) the predicted labels vector.